# Java Filter For Logstash

Tags: java, ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

You know how there is a Ruby filter for Logstash which enables me to write code in Ruby and it is usually included in the config file as follows

```
filter {
      ruby {
           code => "...."
      }
}
```

Now I have two Jar files that I would like to include in my filter so that the input I have can be processed according to the operations I have in these Jar files. However, I cannot (apparently) include the Jar file in the ruby code. I've been looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer this, I found this wonderful tutorial from Elastc.co:

Shows the steps to create a new gem and use it as a filter for Logstash later on.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Orrr to answer your original question,

you *can* include a JAR in your ruby code, but you need to be using jruby,

see instructions here on how to access java code from JARs in JRuby:

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#from-jar-files

> To use resources within a jar file from JRuby, the jar file must
>   either be on the classpath or be made available with the require
>   method:
>
> `require 'path/to/mycode.jar'` This require makes the resources in
>   mycode.jar discoverable by later commands like `import` and
>   `include_package`.
>
> Note that loading jar-files via require searches along the `$LOAD_PATH`
>   for them, like it would for normal ruby files.

Comment: Yes that is correct and that's how I started with my solution, the gem will be written using Jruby (including the jar file), which will be used as a new logstash filter. thanks :)