# Is there any possible to connect logstash to Java?

Tags: java, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am new for logstash and ElasticSearch. I like to know whether is it possible to connect logstash to java.

Here is my question,
I have multiple types of log files and I have to parse these different log files. I don't like to write **logstash filter** for each separate log files and i know, this is not an efficient way. So I decided to create one **configuration file**. which means before running logstash I will configure which field should be parse. So that, the particular filed only parsed in each line of that log file. so we don't need to write logstash filter separately for different log files. Is this method work? or any other suggestions?

Comment: This may help - [Java Filter for Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370646/java-filter-for-logstash)

Comment: this seems more like you do with `grok` filter any way. This strategy can work, but can you post an example at what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is my sample log file parsing in logstash,
input {
 file {
  path => "/Users/MINE/Desktop/sample.log"
  start_position => "beginning"
  sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
 } 
}

filter {
 grok {
  match => { "message" => "(?<time>[\d\s]+)(?<tags>[\[\w\]]+)\s(?<id>[\w]+)\s" 
  }
 }
}


output {
  elasticsearch { 
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
  index => "index_name"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

This is actually one of the log file type filter, so I have to filter all the different log files.